# Can you use SQL to make a database for a HTML website?

Tags: html, sql

I have made a very basic website using HTML. It is basically a template, the thing you start with. I want to use SQL to make a database. I would also like to display all of the data on that screen (index.html). Can you help me achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, not only with SQL.

SQL is a language used to perform queries in a database (inserting data, deleting, searching, etc.). To use it to display data on your website you would also need to learn some other programming language, so you can write code that will serve as an interface between your website and the database. Two most popular choices are Python (with Flask or Django) or NodeJS, I recommend using Python, since it's known to be somewhat beginner-friendly. I suggest finding a tutorial online to get you started.

Happy coding!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/ this should be enough to get you started.

I know it's a lot of material to study, but it will all make sense once you get through it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use the 'sqlalchemy' for the database system. You can look the sqlalchemy documentation to have more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLPage](https://sql.ophir.dev) to build a simple web interface for your database in SQL, without using any other programming language.

That will allow you to build the website in SQL by using either predefined or custom HTML components.

[image: screenshot]

If you know html, you can [build your own components](https://sql.ophir.dev/documentation.sql) for SQLPage just by putting your html files in sqlpage's folder.